# I can't find this game or remember the name

Tags: identify-this-game

I am looking for a game that is played with all the cards in the deck. The cards are placed in a single row, face up, one next to the other. The object is to remove as many as possible. However the rules state you can only remove the cards that are the same in suit or rank, and only if they lie next to the card or three cards to the left.

Example: if you have a 9 diamond, 6 spade, 4 club,  2 diamond, 2 heart, 3 club, K spade, etc. etc..

The 3 club can be moved to the 4 club and the 4 club is removed. The same with the 2 heart, and the 2 diamond. But it would be better to use the 2 diamond to remove the 9 diamond and then the 2 heart to remove the 2 diamond.

I have been looking for this game for years, used to play it all the time but now I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Is this a solo game or multiplayer?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like Accordion:

> Cards are dealt in a single row, from Left to Right [...]  The goal is
>   to move cards onto each other, removing the lower card,  until a
>   single card remains. A card may be moved onto a card on  its direct
>   left, or third on left, if the card matches the [suit or value] of the
>   destination card.

http://www.allgoodsw.com/sol_rules.html#accordion

And see the [Wiki Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_(solitaire)) for variants.